# Postgresql server suddenly rejects connections with no pg_hba.conf entry error - IPV4/IPV6 issue?

Tags: postgresql

There are a lot of questions/answers here describing problems with connection attempts to postgresql being rejected with an error saying "no pg_hba.conf entry for host". All the ones I have read imply that this is a configuration problem that has always existed, and needs fixing. In our case, just before the weekend, suddenly all new connections were (typically) rejected after working fine for literally months (a few attempts worked for a while, but after a few hours, all new connections were rejected).

In all cases, there the error is duplicated - once for SSL on and once for SSL off.

The server is on a Linux PC. We use IPV4 addresses within our office environment, but the host address mentioned in the error is IPV6. Is this a clue as to what may have changed?

Comment: Well, probably someone change `pg_hba.conf`. Postgres most certainly doesn't do that out of the blue. Did you verify that the file hasn't changed and that it still contains the correct content?

Comment: What has changed in your environment? Did you get a new router/firewall? Have you updated workstation or server networking software or postgresql components? Has the SSL certificate expired or been revoked?

Comment: Cannot find any changes at this stage. pg_hba.conf file dated July last year and did not contain `listen_addresses = '*'`. Adding that has made no difference. Still searching for clues... `ipconfig` lists the host address in the error as a `Temporary IPV6 address` for the Wifi adapter.

Comment: `pg_hba.conf` would not contain `listen_addresses` that is in `postgresql.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

We could not trace the cause of this issue, but when one of us swapped from Wifi (fail) to LAN (fail) and back to Wifi, suddenly it connected. Others then turned their Wifi connection off and back on, and connections were restored. However... the original addresses rejected by the Postgresql server are identical to those now in use and listed as temporary IPv6 addresses for the WiFi adapter. It is as if nothing has changed for the client, and yet everything has changed. We cannot explain it.

Comment: If you really want to get to the bottom of this, read the PostgreSQL log entries.